# How do I use TAB instead of Enter for completion in ido-mode?

Tags: ido

When I do `C-x C-f` `.emacs.d/i` `TAB` Emacs displays a new buffer which presents "Possible completions", which are in my case `auto-save-list/`, `history` and `init.el`. I would like to have it complete to just `.emacs.d/init.el`.

I have the following inside `init.el` regarding `ido`:

```el
(require 'ido)
(ido-mode 1)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control this by setting the variable `ido-enable-prefix` to `t`:

```el
(setq ido-enable-prefix t)
```

From the documentation:

> Non-`nil` means only match if the entered text is a prefix of file name.
>   This behavior is like the standard Emacs completion.
>   If `nil`, match if the entered text is an arbitrary substring.
>   Value can be toggled within Ido using `ido-toggle-prefix`.

The value of `ido-enable-flex-matching` does not interfere with this setting.

Of course, if `.emacs.d/i` is a prefix for more than one file, Emacs will still list possible completions.

Comment: It seems like `ido-enable-prefix` means flex matching will never be used. Is there a case I'm missing where having both turned on is useful? I prefer to enable flex matching and then toggle prefix matching on the fly (using `C-p`) when I need it.